# Micromax-P701 bricked, MT6735

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, recovery-mode, boot-loop, unbricking

Micromax-P701-MT6735, Deleted All Partiton, also bricked recovery and fastboot, All MTK Drivers are installed but its continues connecting and disconnecting(the device manager is flashing but not showing mobile) so i cant flash phone. even mobile does not power off, keeps rebooting please help!

Comment: Did you try to flash a firmware that wasn't supposed to be flashed on that device? The scenario you describe typically happens when you do that.

Comment: Another thing is that messing with partitions is the last thing you do on cheap Chinese gizmos (which is essentially what Micromax devices are).

Comment: I didn't flash any custom rom but, i accidentally deleted all root files(etc, system all) now, when i try to flash with sp tool it does not give any respond. and device keeps rebooting even i can't power off it. in device manager not showing any device but device manager is flashing every connects and disconnects. i have installed all mtk drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Emmc of your phone gone to read only state and you r trying to flash phone and also prealoder got damage and cant turn on your phone prealoader is responsible to turn on phone and it get got damage also emmc is read only state so you can flash prealoder from working phone but it will not affect it so just replace emmc and reinstall firmware in it